# C# Wpf store font to bytes then back to font

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, fonts

I want that users can add font to the application (Transferable to any computer without font installed on it). After that font will be stored in to my file. I want convert selected font to bytes and then back to font. I don't want install font. I want private font. In winforms there is class privatefontcollection but in wpf I did'n find anything.

```
    public void StoreFont(string path)
    {
         //Converting font to bytes
         data.FontManager.Add(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
    }

    public System.Windows.Media.FontFamily GetFont(int ID)
    {
        //byte array
        //data.FontManager[ID]
        return new SomethingToConvertByteArrayBackToFontFamily;
    }
```

Is there something to convert bytes to font family?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can only load fonts from disk in WPF.

You have to write to a temporary file and load the font from that.

You don't have to install it though, you can load it from a ttf or otf file.